# script not working on android webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, browser, webview

I use wordpress to make a site and made a script where people can select a radio button and than one more selection shows up. But the script is not working on android standard browser what did I do wrong?

So this is the html form:

```
<form id='form-id' action="http://trainingzuid.nl/wp-content/php/mail.php" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><input id='pt' name='test' type='radio' /> personal training</td>
  <td><input id='gt' name='test' type='radio' /> group training</td>
  <td><input id='bt' name='test' type='radio' /> both</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='pur' style='display:none'>Purpose:</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='gf' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> general fitness</input></div></td>
<td><div id='lw' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> losing weight</div></td>
<td><div id='bt1' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> both</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='kb' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> kickboksen</input></div></td>
<td><div id='b' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> boksen</div></td>
<td><div id='kkb' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> kids kickbosen</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='bf' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> ballet fitness</input></div></td>
<td><div id='ch' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> cross hit</div></td>
<td><div id='t6' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 6</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div id='t7' style='display:none'><input type='radio'> training 7</input></div></td>
<td><div id='t8' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 8</div></td>
<td><div id='t9' style='display:none'><input type='radio' /> training 9</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First and last name"></p></td>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="e-mail adress"></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phonenumber"></p></td>
  <td><p><input type="text" name="message" placeholder="additional message"></p></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table></center>
  <center><input type="submit" value="Submit"></center>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the js script:

```
$('#form-id').change(function() {
    if ($('#pt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#gf').show();
        $('#lw').show();
        $('#bt1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur').hide();
        $('#gf').hide();
        $('#lw').hide();
        $('#bt1').hide();
    }
    if ($('#gt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#kb').show();
        $('#b').show();
        $('#kkb').show();
        $('#bf').show();
        $('#ch').show();
        $('#t6').show();
        $('#t7').show();
        $('#t8').show();
        $('#t9').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur1').hide();
        $('#kb').hide();
        $('#b').hide();
        $('#kkb').hide();
        $('#bf').hide();
        $('#ch').hide();
        $('#t6').hide();
        $('#t7').hide();
        $('#t8').hide();
        $('#t9').hide();
    }
    if ($('#bt').attr('checked')) {
        $('#pur').show();
        $('#gf').show();
        $('#lw').show();
        $('#bt1').show();
    } else {
        $('#pur2').hide();
        $('#gf1').hide();
        $('#lw1').hide();
        $('#bt12').hide();
    }
});
```

I found lot of scripts but this was the only working one on my theme with wordpress.

THNX for all the help!!

Comment: did you enable java script in your code? or you are just checking your web site on browser?

Comment: I put the script between the <script> tags. Yes on my android browser but it's not working there. In other browsers it works fine?

Comment: In order not to add a duplicate possible answer! check the answer of @nayan-srivastava but also try to load the url twice. It maybe won't load the javascript on page load. Also, could you provide the log for this, it might be useful to identify the problem.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided code of your `WebView` thus I can only suggest to check if you have enabled `JavaScript` in your `WebView`.

Try this

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Comment: I tried this. Now the code looks like this: `<script>
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
$('#form-id').change(function() {` and then the rest of it but no succes?

Comment: Hey man, are you trying to use your web code in android app or you are opening a normal webpage in any android browser?

Comment: Just the android webbrowser

Comment: Then re-frame your question and remove andriod tags.